# SQL programming involving combining columns to tables but not with join

Tags: sql

Suppose I have  columns 1, 2, and 3. Also suppose columns 2 and 3 are in the same table but column 1 is not. Finally suppose column 1 and 2 tell the same information (order number),but aren't necessarily in the same ordering, and column 3 holds the price for that order number. How do I add a column to the table 1 is in that copies the information from column 3 but keeps the order number aligned with the price?

Is there a command or do I have to write a function for this?

Comment: SQL tables don't have order, so you would end up with the same data in both tables

Comment: Are you saying SQL tables dont have column order order or row order? I can understand swapping column positions and it not having any effect, but keeping 1 columns row order fixed and then shuffling another's row values doesn't seem like you would want that to happen. Otherwise why have different columns?

Comment: What I am referring to is that you say `column 1 and 2 tell the same information but aren't in the same ordering` and when rows are stored in the tables they don't have a specified ordering.

Comment: Not exactly true @Troveldom, depending on whether the table is a heap or not, the rows are stored on disk in a certain order. When a clustered key is provided the rows are stored on disk in the order of the clustered key. Heaps, however, are stored in insert order, but the DB engine will move rows around in order to store data more efficiently, so you can't guarantee the order without an `ORDER BY`. Just thought I'd point this out!

Comment: I understand that and I appreciate your response but that doesn't answer my question as I'm referring specifically to reading left to right implies relationships in tables while up to down does not. Maybe I didn't word my question well. Anyways someone did answer my question already though so thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: I'm concerned on what you are trying to do, because the two tables created only defer in row order, and as @Charleh correctly pointed out, there can be an order in the rows, but it isn't guaranteed. Keep that in mind

Comment: @user71666 it was really just a reply to the other comment, didn't have much to do with the question tbh (there was already an answer that you'd accepted too) just thought I'd point it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table1:
---Column1 (order number)

Table2:
---Column2 (order number)
---Column3 (price)

SELECT
   T1.Column1,
   T2.Column3
FROM
   Table1 T1 

   INNER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column2
```

(the join keeps the order number aligned with the price)

Comment: !!!! All the examples I read did not approach it like this. They basically said select all 3 and inner join all 3 with 1 = 2. Thank you!!